# Multiple formulae with shared parameters in R

Tags: r, formulas

We're trying to come up with a way for an R function to handle a model which has multiple responses, multiple explanatory variables, and possibly shared parameters between the responses. For example:

```
Y1 ~ X1 + X2 + X3
Y2 ~ X3 + X4
```

specifies two responses and four explanatory variables. X3 appears in both, and we want the user to control whether the associated parameter value is the same or different. ie:

```
Y1 = b1 X1 + b2 X2 + b3 X3
Y2 = b3 X3 + b4 X4
```

which is a model with four 'b' parameters, or

```
Y1 = b1 X1 + b2 X2 + b3 X3
Y2 = b4 X3 + b5 X4
```

a model with five parameters.

Two possibilities:

- Specify all the explanatory variables in one formula and supply a matrix mapping responses to explanatories. In which case

`Foo( Y1+Y2 ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, map=cbind(c(1,1,1,0),c(0,0,1,1)))`

would correspond to the first case, and

```
Foo( Y1+Y2 ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, map=cbind(c(1,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,0,1,1)))
```

would be the second. Obviously some parsing of the LHS would be needed, or it could be `cbind(Y1,Y2)`. The advantage of this notation is that there is also other information that might be required for each parameter - starting values, priors etc - and the ordering is given by the ordering in the formula.

- Have multiple formulae and a grouping function that just adds an attribute so shared parameters can be identified - the two examples then become:

`Foo( Y1 ~ X1+X2+G(X3,1), Y2 ~ G(X3,1)+X4)`

where the X3 parameter is shared between the formula, and

`Foo( Y1 ~ X1+X2+X3, Y2 ~ X3+X4)`

which has independent parameters. The second parameter of `G()` is a grouping ID which gives the power to share model parameters flexibly.

A further explanation of the `G` function is shown by the following:

```
Foo( Y1 + X1+X2+G(X3,1), Y2~G(X3,1)+G(X4,2), Y3~G(X3,3)+G(X4,2), Y4~G(X3,3))
```

would be a model where:

```
Y1 = b1 X1 + b2 X2 + b3 X3
Y2 = b3 X3 + b4 X4
Y3 = b5 X3 + b4 X4
Y4 = b5 X3
```

where there are two independent parameters for X3 (G(X3,1) and G(X3,3)). How to handle a group that refers to a different explanatory variable is an open question - suppose that model had `Y4~G(X3,2)` - that seems to imply a shared parameter between different explanatory variables, since there's a `G(X4,2)` in there.

This notation seems easier for the user to comprehend, but if you also have to specify starting values then the mapping between a vector of starting values and the parameters they correspond to is no longer obvious. I suspect that internally we'd have to compute the mapping matrix from the `G()` notation.

There may be better ways of doing this, so my question is... does anyone know one?

Comment: Will you need to account for more complicated model specifications like these: `Y3 = b5 X3; Y4 = 2*b5 X3`, or `Y3 = b5 X3; Y4 = b5 X4`? (Very interesting question, BTW.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question (I wish all package authors worried a lot more in advance about how they were going to create extensions to the basic Wilkinson-Rogers formula notation ...)

How about something like

```
formula=list(Y1~X1+X2+X3,Y2~X3+X4,Y3~X3+X4,Y4~X3),
   shared=list(Y1+Y2~X3,Y2+Y3~X4,Y3+Y4~X3)
```

or something like that for your second example above?

The `formula` component gives the list of equations.

The `shared` component simply lists which response variables share the same parameter for specified predictor variables.  It could obviously be mapped into a logical or binary table, but (for me at least -- this is certainly in the eye of the beholder) it's more straightforward. I think the `map` solution above is awkward when (as in this case) a variable (such as `X3`) is shared in two distinct sets of relationships.

I guess some straightforward rule like "starting values in the order in which the parameters appear in the list of formulas" -- in this case

```
X1, X2, X3(1), X4, X3(2)
```

would be OK, but it might be nice to provide a helper function that would tell the users the names of the coefficient vector (i.e. the order) given a `formula`/`shared` specification ...

From a bit of personal experience, I would say that embedding more fanciness in the formula itself leads to pain ... for example, the original `nlme` syntax with the random effects specified separately was easier to deal with than the new `lme4`-style syntax with random effects and fixed effects mixed in the same formula ...

An alternative (which I don't like nearly as well) would be

```
 formula=list(Y1~X1+X2+X3,Y2~X3+X4,Y3~X3[2]+X4,Y4~X3[2])
```

where new parameters are indicated by some sort of tag (with `[1]` being implicit).

Also note suggestion from the chat room by @Andrie that interfaces designed for structural equation modeling (`sem`, `lavaan` packages) may be useful references.

Comment: +1, and +5 if I could because this is so definitely the way I would go. Storing the constraints in a separate argument has a nice orthogonality, makes the formulae in both arguments easier to read, and may even make the programming a bit more straightforward. I have the same preference for `nlme` vs `lme4`-style syntax, and even found lattice's conditioning variable (i.e. `|`) harder to pick up than its named `groups=` argument.  If you can at all help it, you really don't want user to have to learn any new syntax/mini-language to use your package.

Comment: Yeah, we like this answer. It might have to wait for v2 of the package though, since doing all this shared parameter business might take a while - v1 will just have independent parameters and one big fat prior (I think...). Its not me writing it...

Answer (score 0):

Of the two methods you propose, the second one with the idea of several formulae looks more natural, but the `G` notation makes no sense to me.

The first one is much easier to understand, but I have two suggested tweaks to the `map` argument.

1. It should really take logical values rather the numbers.
2. Consider having a default of including all the independent variables for each response variable.